# React hooks - calling two functions in one hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that creates a button for each category in an array. Currently, there is one function where, when a category is selected, the posts in that category are listed. There is another function for a "load more" button (pagination), where 5 posts are loaded initially, and onClick, 5 more posts are loaded. Right now, if I'm viewing category "books", and load a few "pages" worth of posts - say I view up to page 3 - when I click over to category "movies", page 3 is what is initially loaded. the current code is:

```
const Posts = ({ state }) => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/categories")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setCategories(data);
      })
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (categoryId) {
      fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + categoryId + "&per_page=5")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPosts(data);
        });
    }
  }, [categoryId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!categoryId) {
      return;
    }
    let url = state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + categoryId + "&per_page=5";
    if (page > 1) {
      url += `&page=${page}`;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts([...posts, ...data]);
      });
  }, [categoryId, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5";
    if (page > 1) {
      url += `&page=${page}`;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setAllPosts([...allPosts, ...data]);
      });
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <>
      {categories.length > 0 ? (
        categories.map((category, i) => {
          return (
            <button key={i} onClick={() => setCategoryId(category.id)}>{category.name}</button>
          )
        })
      ) : (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        )
      }

      <div>
        {posts.length === 0 ? (
          <>
            {allPosts.map((generalPost, i) => {
              return (
                <li key={i}>{generalPost.title.rendered}</li>
              )
            })}
            <button onClick={() => { setPage(page + 1); }}>Load more</button>
          </>
        ) : (
            <>
              <ol>
                {posts.map((post, i) => {
                  console.log(post.id);
                  return (
                    <li key={i}>{post.title.rendered}</li>
                  )
                })}
              </ol>

              <button onClick={() => { setPage(page + 1); }}>Load more</button>
            </>
          )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

I am trying to fix this situation such that when a different category is selected, the posts listed start on page 1. Based on what I have found so far, I am reading that I will need to have two functions wrapped in one. I think I need to create a function that performs both of these:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!categoryId) {
      return;
    }
    let url = state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + categoryId + "&per_page=5";
    if (page > 1) {
      url += `&page=${page}`;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts([...posts, ...data]);
      });
  }, [categoryId, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5";
    if (page > 1) {
      url += `&page=${page}`;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setAllPosts([...allPosts, ...data]);
      });
  }, [page]);
```

I'm confused on how to combine these two functions into one. Any advice or further resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you switch the category, you should reset all the other values too..

just try to replace

```
<button key={i} onClick={() => setCategoryId(category.id)}>{category.name}</button>
```

with

```
<button key={i} onClick={() => {
    setPage(1);
    setPosts([]);
    setCategoryId(category.id);
}}>{category.name}</button>
```